# Apache XML-RPC Exception Handling

Tags: exception, xml-rpc

What is the easiest way to extract the original exception from an exception returned via Apache's implementation of XML-RPC?

Comment: What is the context of this question? Are you using XML-RPC directly?

Comment: I'm using Apache's implementation, namely http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that getting the cause exception from the Apache exception is the right one.

```
} catch (XmlRpcException rpce) {
    Throwable cause = rpce.getCause();
    if(cause != null) {
        if(cause instanceof ExceptionYouCanHandleException) {
            handler(cause);
        }
        else { throw(cause); }
    }
    else { throw(rpce); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [XML-RPC Spec](http://www.xmlrpc.com/spec) it returns the "fault" in the xml.

Is this the "Exception" you are referring to or are you refering to a Java Exception generated while making the XML-RPC call?

**Fault example**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Length: 426
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 1998 19:55:02 GMT
Server: UserLand Frontier/5.1.2-WinNT

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodResponse>
  <fault>
    <value>
      <struct>
      <member>
        <name>faultCode</name>
        <value><int>4</int></value>
      </member>
      <member>
        <name>faultString</name>
        <value>
          <string>Too many parameters.</string>
        </value>
      </member>
      </struct>
    </value>
  </fault>
</methodResponse>
```

Comment: Let's say basic authentication is used... how do you get the header to be HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized rather?